# Limit an UIScrollView to not show blank spaces?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to use an uiwebView, with content I think is inside its scrollView. I want to be able to scroll, but not to show blank parts.

I mean, for example, you have a tall page, so you can scroll down, but when you are at the bottom, you shouldn't be able to continue scrolling. Also when you are at the top you shouldn't be able to scroll down, but it happens by default, and it makes a nasty blank space, does anyone know which properties could I use?

Comment: Please work on formatting and phrasing your question in more comprehensible way. It's hard to tell what's being asked, and even harder to work through the spelling and gramatical issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the `bounces` property of your `UIScrollView` to `NO`.

Please read the documentations before asking such trivial questions...

Comment: Thats not a fair answer to call it "trivial". You dont know if CalixJumi has English as nativ language and if the word "bounce" is responsable for everyone what it means. He explained what he wants and the SDK already have a solution for it. Thats fine.